# Getting parameters from Twilio call without using ASPNet library

Tags: c#, twilio

I would like to get the callerSid parameter from Twilio in a c# solution without using the "using Twilio.AspNet.Common" library.

```
        //here is the code that uses the ASPNET.Common library to get the 
        callerSid
        public ActionResult Index(VoiceRequest request)
        {
        var response = new VoiceResponse();
        List<string> validIds = new List<string> { "12345", "23456", 
        "34567" };
        var userId = request.Digits;
        var callerSid = request.callerSid;
        var authenticated = validIds.Contains(userId);
        if (!authenticated)
```

Here is a picture of what I currently have not used the ASPNet library:

[image: here is a picture of what I currently have not used the ASPNet library]

I don't know if anyone else has used other Twilio helper libraries to get parameters while in the call.

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking here. What is working and not working for you? Why do you not want to use the `Twilio.AspNet.Common` library to help parse the request? What trouble are you having not using it?

Answer (score 0):

Hey Another Twilio Evangelist here...

You should be able to remove that helper library, add the `callSid` parameter to your controller method, and it should automatically get picked up when the route is requested. I'm thinking your code will look something like this...

```cs
public ActionResult Index(string callSid)
{
    string id = callSid;
    .
    .
    .
    return View();
}
```

Drop a note here if you run into trouble. We built a version of this on my Twitch stream which you can also see in video form here - https://www.twitch.tv/cldubya (specifically the 9/3/19).